# tensorflow v1 GradientTape: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'eval'

Tags: tensorflow, signal-processing, gradient, tensorflow1.15

I want to compute the gradient of the distance between the NSynth WaveNet encoding of two sine waves.
This is tensorflow v1.

I am working with code based upon https://github.com/magenta/magenta/blob/master/magenta/models/nsynth/wavenet/fastgen.py

A minimal example of my bug is in this colab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oTEU8QAaOs0K1A0KHrAdt7kA7MkadNDr?usp=sharing

Here is the code:

```
# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
# %tensorflow_version 1.x

!pip3 install -q magenta
!wget -c http://download.magenta.tensorflow.org/models/nsynth/wavenet-ckpt.tar && tar xvf wavenet-ckpt.tar
checkpoint_path = './wavenet-ckpt/model.ckpt-200000'

import math
from magenta.models.nsynth.wavenet import fastgen
import tensorflow as tf

session_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
session_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=session_config)

pi = 3.1415926535897
SR = 16000
sample_length = 64000
DURATION_SECONDS = sample_length / SR

def sine(hz):
  time = tf.linspace(0.0, DURATION_SECONDS, sample_length)
  return tf.constant(0.5) * tf.cos(2.0 * pi * time * hz)

net = fastgen.load_nsynth(batch_size=2, sample_length=sample_length)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)

"""We have two sine waves at 440 and 660 Hz. We use the encoder to generate two (125, 16) encodings:"""

twosines = tf.stack([sine(440), sine(660)]).eval(session=sess)
print(sess.run(net["encoding"], feed_dict={net["X"]: twosines}).shape)

"""Compute the distance between the two sine waves"""

distencode = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(net["encoding"][0] - net["encoding"][1]))
print(sess.run(distencode, feed_dict={net["X"]: twosines}))

"""I don't know why the following code doesn't work, but if I did I could solve the real task....
"""

net["X"] = twosines
distencode.eval(session=sess)

"""Here is the code that I need to work. I want to compute the gradient of the distance between the NSynth encoding of two sine waves:"""

fp = tf.constant(660.0)
newsines = tf.stack([sine(440), sine(fp)])
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
  g.watch(fp)
dd_dfp = g.gradient(distencode, fp)
print(dd_dfp.eval(session=sess))
```

The last block, which I want to evaluate, gets the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-12-b5b8cdd00b24> in <module>()
      4   g.watch(fp)
      5 dd_dfp = g.gradient(distencode, fp)
----> 6 print(dd_dfp.eval(session=sess))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

I believe I need to define the operations to be executed within this block. However, I am using a pretrained model that I am just computing the distance over, so I am not sure how to define execution in that block.

The second-to-last block, which would help me fix the last block, gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-10-c3411dcbfa2c> in <module>()
      3 with tf.GradientTape() as g:
      4   g.watch(fp)
----> 5 dd_dfp = g.gradient(distencode, g)
      6 print(dd_dfp.eval(session=sess))

/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/eager/backprop.py in gradient(self, target, sources, output_gradients, unconnected_gradients)
    997     flat_sources = [_handle_or_self(x) for x in flat_sources]
    998     for t in flat_sources_raw:
--> 999       if not t.dtype.is_floating:
   1000         logging.vlog(
   1001             logging.WARN, "The dtype of the source tensor must be "

AttributeError: 'GradientTape' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
   1366     except errors.OpError as e:

8 frames

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [2,64000]
     [[{{node Placeholder}}]]
     [[Mean/_759]]
  (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [2,64000]
     [[{{node Placeholder}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1385 
   1386   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [2,64000]
     [[node Placeholder (defined at /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
     [[Mean/_759]]
  (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [2,64000]
     [[node Placeholder (defined at /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Original stack trace for 'Placeholder':
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 664, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 438, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1451, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 548, in <lambda>
    self.io_loop.add_callback(lambda : self._handle_events(self.socket, 0))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 462, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 492, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 444, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-5120c8282e75>", line 1, in <module>
    net = fastgen.load_nsynth(batch_size=2, sample_length=sample_length)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/magenta/models/nsynth/wavenet/fastgen.py", line 64, in load_nsynth
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, sample_length])
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2619, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6669, in placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you mean to type `g.gradient(distencode, fp)`. Else you might need to explain what you want that line to do.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the typo. There is a new error message now.